# how to display total orders in django template within a loop

Tags: django, templates, count

hie i want to display the order for each customer within a loop this is my view

```
def clientes(request):
all_clientes = Utilizadores.objects.filter(user_type='cliente')

all_orders = Checkout.objects.all()
context={'all_clientes':all_clientes,'all_orders':all_orders}

return render(request,'todos-clientes.html',context)
```

my template:

```
  {% for all_clientes in all_clientes %}
    <div class="item_wrapp">
      <div class="contxt _7000">
        <div class="img-def-doc-2 _9090903">
           {% if  all_clientes.imagem%}
          <div class="img_cliente"style="background-image: url({{ all_clientes.imagem.url }}");> 
         </div>
          {% else %}
          <div class="img_cliente"></div>
          {% endif%}
        </div>
        <div class="main_name_do_wrapp">
          <div class="nome_produto">{{all_clientes.nome}}</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="extra_item_1_wrapp produto">

            {% for all_orders in all_orders %}
            {% if all_orders.user_id == all_clientes.id %}

          <div class="data num_encomendas_cliente">{{ 
           all_orders.user_id|length }} encomendas(here should be displayed the number of orders for this particular customer) </div>
              {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}

 class Checkout(models.Model):
user_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
order_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self
```

class Utilizadores(models.Model): nome= models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True) def str(self): return self

`

any help i would appreciate thank you.

Comment: Show **models.py**. Do you have a foreign key relationship between client and order? As then you only need to render in context for client and access orders via client.

Comment: im doing the join by this code the problem is displaying as loop not the number of order for that particular client

Comment: {% for all_orders in all_orders %}
                {% if all_orders.user_id == all_clientes.id %}

              <div class="data num_encomendas_cliente">{{ all_orders.user_id|length }} encomendas </div>

                  {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}

Comment: Please can you put them in the question via *edit*. Also include model `Utilizadores` and I'll show you how to tie them together.